# Filtering data using textbox and checkboxes simultaneously with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I wanted to filter my attractions stored in paragraphs by following using jQuery with:

- Textbox, where I put `substring` the attraction starts with
- Checkboxes, which should show only attractions with certain categories. When you tick multiple boxes, it should show items which have any of listed categories.

I have done that, but these filters don't work simultaneously. One filter overrides results of another, because they work on whole list and invoke `show()` and `hide()` on whole list separately.

**Html:**

```html
<h3>Search:</h3>
<div>
  <input type="text" id="search-box" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">
</div>
<h3>Categories:</h3>
<div id="options" class="checkbox">
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox" rel="club">Club</label>
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox" rel="other">Other</label>
</div>
<div id="attractions" style="font-size: x-large">
  <p class="club" style="display: block;"><a href="/TouristAttractions/1">Cocomo</a>
  </p>
  <p class="club" style="display: block;"><a href="/TouristAttractions/2">Princess</a>
  </p>
  <p class="club" style="display: block;"><a href="/TouristAttractions/3">Le Secret</a>
  </p>
  <p class="other" style="display: block;"><a href="/TouristAttractions/4">Wyspa piasek</a>
  </p>
  <p class="other" style="display: block;"><a href="/TouristAttractions/5">C# Operational Base</a>
  </p>
</div>
```

**Javascript:**

```js
$('div.checkbox').delegate('input[type=checkbox]', 'change', function() {

  var $lis = $('#attractions > p').hide();
  var $checked = $('input:checked');

  if ($checked.length) {
    ($checked).each(function() {
      $lis.filter('.' + $(this).attr('rel')).show();
    }).find('input:checkbox').change();
  } else {
    $lis.show();
  }
});

$('#search-box').keyup(function() {
  var valThis = this.value.toLowerCase();

  $('div#attractions > p').each(function() {
    var text = $(this).text(),
      textL = text.toLowerCase();
    (textL.indexOf(valThis) === 0) ? $(this).show(): $(this).hide();
  });

});
```

I suppose there must be some way to achieve simultaneous results. I'd be grateful for showing me right direction, maybe even suggesting to drop this code and use some filter plug-in?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this solves your problem in a clean and clear way. Explanations are in the comments.

```
//Triger filterAttractions when something changes.
$("#search-box, #options input").change(filterAttractions);
$("#search-box").keyup(filterAttractions);

function filterAttractions() {
    //Get the text of the textbox.
    var searchtext = $("#search-box").val();
    //Get an array with the rel attributes of the checked checkboxes.
    var categories = $("#options input:checked").map(function() {
        return $(this).attr("rel");
    }).get();
    //Perform this once for every attraction.
    $("#attractions p").each(function() {
        var attraction = $(this);
        //See if it has any of the checked categories.
        var category = false;
        for(i=0; i<categories.length; i++)
            if(attraction.hasClass(categories[i]))
                category = true;
        //See if it starts with the right text.
        var text = attraction.text().indexOf(searchtext) === 0
        //Show or hide the attraction depending on the result.
        attraction.toggle(category && text);
    });
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5t6kw7tp/1/).

Comment: That is exactly what I was trying to achieve, thank you for your help!

Comment: That is a complete rewrite.

Comment: No. Just wasted my time trying to fix the existing script.

Comment: @mplungjan I don't think pointing out where the error is is a waste of time. On the contrary, I think it can be educational for both the OP and future visitors. Both approaches - rewrite and fixing - have merits, and having answers of both kinds is good.

Comment: @mplungjan Sorry that I didn't thank you for your time spent fixing my script. Although I'm still new in stackoverflow community and I'm still adapting to it's flow, it was very rude of me for just leave your post without feedback. Thank you sincerely for answer to my question.